# How to push object literals as key-value pairs to array?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

What is the best way to separate each pairs into array?

```
const myObject = {
  firstName: 'John',
  surname: 'Doe',
  city: 'New York'
}
```

**to:**

```
[{'firstName': 'John'}, {'surname': 'Doe'}, {'city': 'New York'}]
```

Btw, old posts suggest lodash mapping

```
const newArray = _.map(myObject, (value, key) => ({key, value}))
```

but it would return something like:

```
[ { key: 'firstName', value: 'John' },
 { key: 'surname', value: 'Doe' },
 { key: 'city', value: 'New York' } ]
```

I don't want the keys to be there.

Comment: Change to `({ [key]: value })`

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot! If you put it in an answer, I will tag the question answered. Thanks again!

Comment: `Object.entries(myObject).map(([p, v]) => ({[p]: v}))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the required result using plain JS:

```
Object.keys(myObject).map(key => ({[key]: myObject[key]}));
```

This approach uses [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) of ES2015.

As suggested in comments, you can use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) as well:

```
Object.entries(myObject).map(([p, v]) => ({[p]: v}))
```

If you want to use lodash anyway, you should surround `key` with square brackets:

```
const newArray = _.map(myObject, (value, key) => ({[key], value}))
```

Comment: You're right, I went for your first option. Thanks!